# Running python under nginx

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi

I'm at a loss here...

I'm trying to use uwsgi to run my flask app. Using the example at [WSGI Quick Start](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html#the-first-wsgi-application) I get it to run.

For development (restserver.py):

```
 from api import app

 if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run(debug=True, port=8080)
```

How would I start the uwsgi server with this?

I have tried this (restserver.fcgi):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from flup.server.fcgi import WSGIServer
from api import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    WSGIServer(app, bindAddress='/var/run/fcgi.sock').run()
```

but when reading more I see that uwsgi want's to call the method `application` by default. I can change that of course but I don't have and `application` method so when running:

```
/usr/local/bin/uwsgi --http :9090 --wsgi-file restserver.fcgi
```

I get the following message in the start log:

```
unable to find "application" callable in file restserver.fcgi
```

Comment: Have you edited your uwsgi.ini file? I was configuring nginx with uswsgi and flask recently, and it was painful, but I managed to do this, one thing I remember is that you need to specify callable in your uwsgi.ini file, you should specify app as callable there, and it should fix this error. I have something like this there: callable = app. There is also an option touch-reload, and I have there a path to runserver.py touch-reload = /home/###/bla/bla/run.py. Hope this helps somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is to change start command to

```
/usr/local/bin/uwsgi --http :9090 --wsgi-file restserver.fcgi --callable app
```

or change the way you import your flask application in `restserver.fcgi` to

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from flup.server.fcgi import WSGIServer
from api import app as application

if __name__ == '__main__':
    WSGIServer(application, bindAddress='/var/run/fcgi.sock').run()
```

[Docs on using uWSGI with Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/uwsgi/)

PS: Actually your flask `app` *is* WSGI application.

Comment: thanks. I realized that minutes after I'd posted the question. I was looking at fast-cgi before hence the restserver.fcgi. Now I can just use the normal `restserver.py` file to start it.